# Converting a query to parameterized prepared statements in java jdbc template

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, sql-injection, parameterized-query

How can I convert a normal query to parameterized prepared statement in spring JDBC? Following is the piece of query I am trying to change:

```
private String queryBuilder(Request request, Map<String, String> action) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.append("select * " +
                   "from google_play " +
                   "where ID = '" + request.getId() + "' and " +
                   "SYS_CD = '" + request.getSystemCd() + "' and " +
                   "SYS_DT >='"+request.getSystemDate+"'");
    return builder.toString();
}
```

Can someone suggest a proper way to change this query to avoid sql injection? I have googled a solution for this but couldn't find an exact one.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest starting to use Spring's JDBCTemplate, It will help you to sanitize the queries:

This will give you the option to specify parameters in the following fashion:

```
final String QUERY = "select * " +
        "from google_play " +
        "where ID = ? and " +
        "SYS_CD = ? and " +
        "SYS_DT >= ?);
```

And then query it with:

```
YOUR_CLASS[] yourArray = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(QUERY, request.getId(), request.getSystemCd(), request.getSystemDate, YOUR_CLASS[]);
```

The YOUR_CLASS can be for example a Person, if you are querying the Person table, I believe in your case it would be something like, a GooglePlay entity.

There are really good tutorials out there:

- https://www.baeldung.com/spring-jdbc-jdbctemplate
- https://www.journaldev.com/17053/spring-jdbctemplate-example
- https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-jdbctemplate-querying-examples/
- https://www.baeldung.com/spring-jdbc-jdbctemplate

Comment: Thank you for the reply. do i need to assign to variable or is it your_class[]

Comment: how can i append colons with the ( ? ) like id='1234'